# WCF RestFull "413 Request Entity Too Large"

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

Hi I working whit a WCF RestFull services, using JsonNet to serialize my objects
I have this  have this method:
The User object have a property type byte[] like this

```
public class User
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string UserName {get;set}
   public byte[] Photo {get;set;}
}
```

but wen I make a POST whit a Photo's size more than 41 Kb a got the HttpStatusCode "413 Request Entity Too Large"

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT",
         RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
         UriTemplate = "/user/{id}/")]
        public Stream EditUser(string id, Stream input)
        {
            try
            {
                string json = input.ConvertToString();
                User usr = json.FromJSON<User>();
                usr.Update();

                return null;
            }             
            catch (Exception ex)
            {  
                SetInternalServerErrorResponse();
                return GetResponseError(ex);
            }
        }
```

this is my webconfig

```
<bindings>
              <basicHttpBinding>
                  <binding name="" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
                      <readerQuotas maxDepth="35" maxStringContentLength="65536000" maxArrayLength="65536000" maxBytesPerRead="65536000" />
                      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                  </binding> 
              </basicHttpBinding>
              <webHttpBinding>
                  <binding name="svcBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">               
                      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                      <security mode="None">
                      </security>
                  </binding>
              </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
```

EDIT: I find the solution here:

[maxReceivedMessageSize not fixing 413: Request Entity Too Large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636407/maxreceivedmessagesize-not-fixing-413-request-entity-too-large)

The first response for the post.

Adding the bindingConfiguration proprety.

```
  <service  behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" name="Aloes.Services.Service">
     <endpoint  address="" behaviorConfiguration="web"  binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="svcBinding"
      contract="Aloes.Services.IService" />
    </service>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [maxReceivedMessageSize not fixing 413: Request Entity Too Large](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636407/maxreceivedmessagesize-not-fixing-413-request-entity-too-large)

Answer (score 5):

To overcome this error you need to configure WebHttpBinding in your config file (app.config or web.config):

```
<system.servicemodel>  
    <bindings>  
        <webHttpBinding>  
            <binding maxbufferpoolsize="2147483647"
                     maxreceivedmessagesize="2147483647"
                     maxbuffersize="2147483647"> 
            </binding>  
        </webHttpBinding>  
    </bindings>  
</system.servicemodel>
```

You need to set the `maxbufferpoolsize`, `maxreceivedmessagesize` and `maxbuffersize`.