# WCF Unable to upload large image files

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I have created a WCF REST in .net and I am unable to upload large files on server. When I test the things it will show me error on PostMan Client.

> 413 Request Too Large

I have changed the web settings. to this.

```
<webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
```

This is me request stream.

Unable to paste my request stream.

Comment: have you looked at this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048023/wcf-restfull-413-request-entity-too-large
Probably a duplicate

Comment: *Why did you removed this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/39340935/1679310 if I gave you really working answer?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to check.

First, did you assign the "webHttpBinding" to an explicit endpoint?   Something like this, in the `<system.serviceModel>` section:

```
<services>
  <service name="YourServiceName">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding"
              contract="FullyQualified.IContractName" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Unless you assign the configuration "webHttpBinding" to an endpoint via the `bindingConfiguration` attribute, the default (smaller) values for `webHttpBinding` will be used.

Alternatively, you could make the configuration you specified the default for `webHttpBinding` by omitting the `name` attribute in the `<binding>` element.

Another thing to check is the `maxRequestLength` value in the `<httpRuntime>` element in your config file.  You can specify a maximum value of 2147483647 (`Int32.MaxValue`, basically) in the `<system.web>` section of your config file, like this:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
</system.web>
```