# (413) Request Entity Too Large, settings doesn't work

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, sharepoint-2013

I want to send a large amount of data via a WSF service. The service works, the problem is when I attached big files (1MB) to the information to send.

I did a search for this issue on Stackoverflow and i found this question: [IIS7 - (413) Request Entity Too Large | uploadReadAheadSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122957/iis7-413-request-entity-too-large-uploadreadaheadsize)

I set up my app.config as I read but it doesn't work, I get the same error. This is my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="HelpDeskBPMEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.ModelReparaliaView.csdl|res://*/Model.ModelReparaliaView.ssdl|res://*/Model.ModelReparaliaView.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MAMSQLT01;initial catalog=ProcesosBackOffice;user id=User_ro_HD;password=@n@cl3t;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

This is my service:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true"
    Service="Rep.RepService, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
    CodeBehind="RepService.svc.cs"
    Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory,
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
    PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

What did I forget?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may forgot  <readerQuotas ... /> ??

Comment: You also showing only either the service or the client binding configuration - are they identical?

Comment: I do not client binding configuration. I'm sorry, I'm really newbie. 

@curiousBoy I added but it still doesn't work

Comment: check this post as well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636407/maxreceivedmessagesize-not-fixing-413-request-entity-too-large    and definitely this one too:
http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2328/413-request-entity-too-large-error-with-uploading-a-file

Comment: I did the second change. About the first link, I don't understand what changes I have to do. I guess I have to set the size, but unfortunately I don't know how