# How to call large string through ajax call in WCF Rest service

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf, wcf-rest

My problem is that When I am passing large value of string in data it will not call service and go in error.It works fine when string value is small
If I am passing large value in value of documentbody then it creates problem.
Code:

```
var requestData = {
                "PostData": [{ "Key": "subject", "Value": "e1 note"},{ "Key": "documentbody", "Value": "", "Datatype": "String" }],
            };


 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:32911/Service1.svc/savedata",
    data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, status, XMLHttpRequest) {
        debugger;
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert("error"+xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

My class in c#:

```
public class RequestData
{
     [DataMember]
        public List<PostData> PostData { get; set; }
}
 public class PostData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Error in console:

> "NetworkError: 413 Request Entity Too Large -
>   http://localhost:33919/Service1.svc/savedata"

Comment: could you provide the exception / error?

Comment: This sounds like you just need to alter your web.config to cope with larger Request sizes:  http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/ASPNet/FileUpload.htm

Comment: @Gelootn I am getting this error ""NetworkError: 413 Request Entity Too Large - http://localhost:33911/Service1.svc/savedata" in console.

Comment: @MikeGledhill When I am trying "<system.web><httpRuntimemaxRequestLength="50000"/>
</system.web>" It gives me internal server error

Comment: Probably this is what you might be expecting check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636407/maxreceivedmessagesize-not-fixing-413-request-entity-too-large

Comment: @Arvind Thanx it works.